# Which characters are allowed in MarkLogic 8 usernames and roles?

Tags: marklogic

I try to setup a user in MarkLogic with a username equal to an email adres("demo@wildspaces.com"), seems I can create the user but not the corresponding role.

I created the user but when I want to add a role to it like so:

```
sec.userAddRoles(user,role)
```

this gives an error like:

```
2016-03-11 20:00:48.820 Notice: api-cluey-app: in /v1/projects.sjs, at 182:26, in projPost() [javascript]
2016-03-11 20:00:48.820 Notice: api-cluey-app: in [anonymous], at 1:67,
2016-03-11 20:00:48.820 Notice: api-cluey-app: in xdmp:eval("declareUpdate(); var sec = require('/MarkLogic/security.xqy'); s...", {role:"scc-proj-8327360-owner", user:"bill@wildspaces.com"}, {isolation:"different-transaction", userId:"11821709629759202109", database:"17312114676051821586"}) [javascript]
2016-03-11 20:00:48.820 Notice: api-cluey-app: in /v1/projects.sjs [javascript]
2016-03-11 20:00:48.820 Notice: api-cluey-app: in /v1/projects.sjs [javascript]
2016-03-11 20:00:49.416 Info: api-cluey-app: Status 500: XDMP-LEXVAL: sec:role-name("bill@wildspaces.com") -- Invalid lexical value "demo@wildspaces.com"
```

And if I try to look into the admin security db it gets worse:

```
You've encountered an error in the server. If you have a maintenance contract, you can open a support ticket by copying the text below and emailing support@marklogic.com. Otherwise, please see our community Q & A resources for help with this issue:
500: Internal Server Error
XDMP-LEXVAL: sec:role-name("demo@wildspaces.com") -- Invalid lexical value "demo@wildspaces.com"
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/session.xqy on line 595
In get-session-role()
$role = ()
$u = fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/6750406636815962640")/sec:role
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/nav-format.xqy on line 2486
In role-nav("security", "summary", "role", "")
$section = "security"
$panel = "summary"
$param = "role"
$icon = ""
$t = "section=security"
$npan = "summary"
$u = fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/6966198486234205304")/sec:role
$uid = fn:doc("http://marklogic.com/xdmp/roles/6966198486234205304")/sec:role/sec:role-id
$args = "section=security&amp;role=6966198486234205304"
$uname = sec:role-name("davida")
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/nav-format.xqy on line 2392
In security-nav("security", "summary", "role", "")
$section = "security"
$panel = "summary"
$param = "role"
$icon = ""
$panel = "summary"
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/nav-format.xqy on line 2358
In printNav("security", "summary", "role", "")
$section = "security"
$panel = "summary"
$param = "role"
$icon = ""
$sec = "security"
$start-time = xs:dayTimeDuration("PT0.001403S")
In /MarkLogic/Admin/lib/role-summary-form.xqy on line 87
In roleSummaryPage()
In /role-summary.xqy on line 16
```

So my question: What characters are allowed in valid MarkLogic usernames and role? Can't seem to find any documentation on that?

Comment: Really tricky that the security database does not complain while creating the user?

Comment: What mechanism did you use to create the user?

Comment: xdmp:eval(sec:create-user-with-role(..))  strange I can create a user via admin/security/users/create but not a role ... seems there is a check on the role but not on the user ... so if you create a role like this then you are in trouble

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find type definitions in the schemas that are shipped with MarkLogic. On a Mac, they're in `~/Library/MarkLogic/Config`; on Linux, `/opt/MarkLogic/Config/`. The schema in question is `security.xsd`, which has the following type definition for `role-name`:

```
<xs:simpleType name="role-name">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:documentation>
    </xs:documentation>
    <xs:appinfo>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

`xs:NMTOKEN` is defined here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-Nmtoken. It's a valid [`NameStartChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-NameStartChar) followed by any number of [`NameChar`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#NT-NameChar). <s>In other words, it's a valid XML local name.</s> (**Update**: this is incorrect; an XML local-name is more restrictive than an NMTOKEN.)

In XQuery, you could check for valid names like this:

```
"demo@wildspaces.com" castable as xs:NMTOKEN
```

which returns `false`.

**Update**:

Sorry I missed the follow-up question.

All XML Schema types have built-in constructor/conversion functions, which work by applying a type-cast to their arguments. Those type constuctors are available in server-side JS, under the global `xs` object:

```
var isValid
try {
  isValid = !!xs.NMTOKEN("test%")
} catch(err) {
  isValid = false
}
```

Comment: who do I check the name to be castable in serverside java script?